# What is the restful way to delete multiple items in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to delete multiple records in rails by passing the multiple values to REST api?. 
My current routes looks like this:

```
products DELETE /products/:id(.:format)   products#destroy
```

When I try to pass multiple values as as an array (DELETE /products/[ids]), it says the routes doesn't exists.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot research, I have figured out a way to delete multiple records by passing the ids as a comma separated values to REST api.

You have call the API like this

```
DELETE /products/id1,id2,id3
```

Now handle the business logic in your controller

```
Product.where(id: params[:id].split(',')).destroy_all
```

Comment: Thanks @vasu-adari for review

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing that pass an array of ids and use [destroy_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all)

```
Product.where(id: params[:ids]).destroy_all
```